# Retry for python requests module hanging

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

I had to use the request module to fetch a huge number of URLs. Due to network errors, I wanted to implement the Retry mechanism. So my code looks like this:

```
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from requests.packages.urllib3.util.retry import Retry
import requests

session = requests.Session()
retry = Retry(total=1,backoff_factor=0.5,status_forcelist=(500,502,504,503))
adapter = HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retry)
session.mount('http://', adapter)
session.mount('https://',adapter)        
head_response = session.get(url,timeout=2)
```

However, the code keeps hanging when the URL is: tiffins.NET. A normal requests.get with timeout=2 gives 503 status code but doesn't hang.

Am I doing something wrong?

I'm using python 2.7.15rc1.

Answer (score 6):

Just had the same problem and figured out that it's because of the website's header "Retry-After". By default, Retry uses that value to wait until the next request. To ignore it, set the `respect_retry_after_header` parameter to `False` when creating a Retry object.

Comment: This totally saved me today! Thank you very much!

Comment: Saved me too.  OP forgot to accept this answer apparently.